# CodeDeploy Blue-Green Deployment Failure: Original Environment Issue, Instance Startup Failed

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am encountering an issue with a CodeDeploy blue-green deployment. The deployment failed due to problems in the original environment, specifically, the instance failed to start. I've checked the deployment logs and events in the AWS CodeDeploy console, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause of the failure.

Details:

- The deployment is set up for a blue-green strategy.
- During the deployment to the green environment, the original environment encountered a failure.
- The EC2 instance in the original environment failed to start, and there's no clear indication as to why in the logs.
- I've verified the AMI, security groups, and network configurations, and everything seems to be in order.
- I also checked the Auto Scaling Group settings for any misconfigurations, but everything appears to be set up correctly.

I need assistance in identifying the root cause of the failure and guidance on how to resolve it. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into troubleshooting CodeDeploy blue-green deployments, your help would be greatly appreciated.

The attached image shows the error message displayed on the CodeDeploy console when the original environment failed.

[Deployment status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9lXg.png)

[Deployment lifecycle events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dguXN.png)

[Instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWxYv.png)

[Original Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvSPq.png)

I attempted to resolve the software issue by first checking the application logs for any error messages. Following that, I updated to the latest version of the software and restarted the server. I also reviewed the relevant documentation and community forums for similar issues. My expectation was that these steps would identify and resolve the problem, allowing the software to run without errors.

Comment: Maybe the codedeploy agent on the original instance does not have internet connectivity so it cannot connect to codedeploy. You can check your networking? Security groups, subnet, nat gateway , route tables etc. Or use network access analyzer

Comment: What are the functions of Original and Replacement in Environment in Deployment lifecycle events? Why is the Original instance not started?

Comment: I am a newbie, if you have time and would like to bother please take a look at the pictures and analyze them, thank you.